# logrotate does not compress /var/log/messages

Tags: linux, log-files, logging, syslog, logrotate

Over time I noticed some logs in `/var/log` such as `auth`, `kern` and `messages` were getting huge. I made `logrotate` entries for them:

```
$ cat /etc/logrotate.d/auth.log 
/var/log/kern.log {
    rotate 5
    daily
}
$ cat /etc/logrotate.d/kern.log 
/var/log/kern.log {
    rotate 5
    daily
}
$ cat /etc/logrotate.d/messages 
/var/log/messages {
    rotate 5
    daily
    postrotate
        /bin/killall -HUP syslogd
    endscript
}
```

also I have the `compress` option enabled:

```
$ grep compress /etc/logrotate.conf 
# uncomment this if you want your log files compressed
compress
```

This works great for `auth.log`, `kern.log` and others, meaning that each of those logs is gzipped and rotated, with the last 5 days of logs retained. `/var/log/messages` however is *not* being compressed, resulting in way more than 5 days of logs:

```
$ ls /var/log/messages*
/var/log/messages           /var/log/messages-20100213
/var/log/messages-20100201  /var/log/messages-20100214
/var/log/messages-20100202  /var/log/messages-20100215
/var/log/messages-20100203  /var/log/messages-20100216
/var/log/messages-20100204  /var/log/messages-20100217
/var/log/messages-20100205  /var/log/messages-20100218
/var/log/messages-20100206  /var/log/messages-20100219
/var/log/messages-20100207  /var/log/messages-20100220
/var/log/messages-20100208  /var/log/messages-20100221
/var/log/messages-20100209  /var/log/messages-20100222
/var/log/messages-20100210  /var/log/messages-20100223
/var/log/messages-20100211  /var/log/messages-20100224
/var/log/messages-20100212
```

As is explained in [another `logrotate` question on ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/76541/logrotate-creates-long-names-and-does-not-delete-logs), the old logs are (most likely) not being removed because the file endings are different for each file. This appears to be because the files are not being gzipped.

What can I do to have `/var/log/messages` compressed and rotated with the last 5 days of logs retained just like all my other log files? What am I missing?

**EDIT 1**: additional information as requested in the first couple answers.

I'm running Gentoo Linux. My `/etc/logrotate.conf` file:

```
$ cat /etc/logrotate.conf 
# $Header: /var/cvsroot/gentoo-x86/app-admin/logrotate/files/logrotate.conf,v 1.3 2008/12/24 20:49:10 dang Exp $
#
# Logrotate default configuration file for Gentoo Linux
#
# See "man logrotate" for details
# rotate log files weekly
weekly
#daily
# keep 4 weeks worth of backlogs
rotate 4
# create new (empty) log files after rotating old ones
create
# use date as a suffix of the rotated file
dateext
# uncomment this if you want your log files compressed
compress
# packages can drop log rotation information into this directory
include /etc/logrotate.d
notifempty
nomail
noolddir
# no packages own lastlog or wtmp -- we'll rotate them here
/var/log/wtmp {
    monthly
    create 0664 root utmp
    rotate 1
}
/var/log/btmp {
    missingok
    monthly
    create 0600 root utmp
    rotate 1
}
```

`/etc/logrotate.d` contains my custom config files as mentioned above along with configs for mysql, rsync, etc installed by those packages.

My root `crontab` is empty:

```
$ sudo crontab -l
no crontab for root
```

I checked all `/etc/cron.{daily,hourly,monthly,weekly}` for anything syslog related, and there's a script which rotates `/var/log/syslog` and `/var/log/auth.log`.

Next, I made a `/var/log/messages`-only `logrotate` config file as suggested by CarpeNoctem:

```
$ cat logrotate-messages 
weekly
rotate 4
create
dateext
compress
notifempty
nomail
noolddir
/var/log/messages {
    rotate 5
    daily
    postrotate
        /bin/killall -HUP syslogd
    endscript
}
```

Then I ran `logrotate` manually:

```
$ logrotate -d logrotate-messages -f
reading config file logrotate-messages
reading config info for /var/log/messages 

Handling 1 logs

rotating pattern: /var/log/messages  forced from command line (5 rotations)
empty log files are not rotated, old logs are removed
considering log /var/log/messages
  log needs rotating
rotating log /var/log/messages, log->rotateCount is 5
dateext suffix '-20100224'
glob pattern '-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
glob finding old rotated logs failed
renaming /var/log/messages to /var/log/messages-20100224
creating new /var/log/messages mode = 0644 uid = 0 gid = 0
running postrotate script
running script with arg /var/log/messages : "
        /bin/killall -HUP syslogd
"
compressing log with: /bin/gzip
$ which gzip
/bin/gzip
$ file /bin/gzip
/bin/gzip: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.9, stripped
```

According to the log above, `logrotate` compressed the log with /bin/gzip, but I don't see a compressed messages file in `/var/log`. Also, globbing for old rotated files failed.

**EDIT 2**: adding debug output of `logrotate` run after appending a `.gz` suffix to old `/var/log/message-*` files.

We start out with:

```
$ ls /var/log/messages*
/var/log/messages              /var/log/messages-20100222.gz
/var/log/messages-20100219.gz  /var/log/messages-20100223.gz
/var/log/messages-20100220.gz  /var/log/messages-20100224.gz
/var/log/messages-20100221.gz
```

Then run `logrotate` with our custom config file:

```
$ logrotate -d logrotate-messages -f
reading config file logrotate-messages
reading config info for /var/log/messages 

Handling 1 logs

rotating pattern: /var/log/messages  forced from command line (5 rotations)
empty log files are not rotated, old logs are removed
considering log /var/log/messages
  log needs rotating
rotating log /var/log/messages, log->rotateCount is 5
dateext suffix '-20100224'
glob pattern '-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
removing /var/log/messages-20100219.gz
removing old log /var/log/messages-20100219.gz
destination /var/log/messages-20100224.gz already exists, skipping rotation
```

This time, `logrotate`'s glob succeeds and finds the sixth compressed logfile, intending to remove it. The file isn't actually removed; I guess that's because we're running in debug mode.

I'm curious whether enabling the `delaycompress` option for `/var/log/messages` will help. I enabled it and will check the results the next morning.

Comment: Can you post your logrotate.conf? Nothing in the excerpts you've shared so far would explain the date suffix on those messages files. Logrotate didn't used to support date suffixes on rotated log files. This leads me to believe that something else entirely is creating those files. Check /etc/crontab, root's crontab and /etc/cron.daily to see if you have another script trying todo the same job.

Comment: in addition to this, can you tell us what distribution of linux you're running?  Debian/Ubuntu has its own log rotation script that could be mucking up your logrotate stuff.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm running Gentoo Linux. My crontabs are not doing any management of /var/log/messages. Please see the new info in my question for details.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Adding `delaycompress` to the configuration section for `/var/log/messages` solved the problem.

From `man logrotate`:

```
   delaycompress
          Postpone  compression of the previous log file to the next rota‐
          tion cycle.  This only has effect when used in combination  with
          compress.   It  can  be used when some program cannot be told to
          close its logfile and thus might continue writing to the  previ‐
          ous log file for some time.
```

I guess [`sysklogd`](http://www.infodrom.org/projects/sysklogd/), my syslog daemon, cannot be told to close its logfile, and thus this is necessary.

Interestingly, the original configuration I had (without the `delaycompress` directive), came straight out of `man logrotate` (except I changed `weekly` to `daily`):

```
   # sample logrotate configuration file
   compress

   /var/log/messages {
       rotate 5
       weekly
       postrotate
           /usr/bin/killall -HUP syslogd
       endscript
   }
```

Comment: It is saying unknown unknown option 'delalycompress'  # logrotate -v /etc/logrotate.d/apc_rtbinfo.conf
reading config file /etc/logrotate.d/apc_rtbinfo.conf
reading config info for /mnt/log/frengo/apc_rtbinfo.log
error: /etc/logrotate.d/apc_rtbinfo.conf:7 unknown option 'delalycompress' -- ignoring line

Handling 1 logs

Comment: # cat /etc/logrotate.d/apc_rtbinfo.conf
/mnt/log/frengo/apc_rtbinfo.log {
daily
missingok
notifempty
size 2000M
compress
delalycompress
sharedscripts
copytruncate
rotate 3
}

Comment: ok got the error there was typo in "delalycompress"

Comment: But now issue is that log.1 is more than 2000M# du -sh /mnt/log/frengo/apc_rtbinfo.log*
0       /mnt/log/frengo/apc_rtbinfo.log
4.7G    /mnt/log/frengo/apc_rtbinfo.log.1
80M     /mnt/log/frengo/apc_rtbinfo.log.2
0       /mnt/log/frengo/apc_rtbinfo.log-20151222
679M    /mnt/log/frengo/apc_rtbinfo.log-20151225.gz
681M    /mnt/log/frengo/apc_rtbinfo.log-20151226.gz
691M    /mnt/log/frengo/apc_rtbinfo.log-20151227.gz
0       /mnt/log/frengo/apc_rtbinfo.log-20151228
70M     /mnt/log/frengo/apc_rtbinfo.log.2.gz
80M     /mnt/log/frengo/apc_rtbinfo.log.3
80M     /mnt/log/frengo/apc_rtbinfo.log.4

Answer (score 6):

It's hard to say with just this info, but I can tell you what has saved me a few times.

Logrotate has a debug option that will print a play-by-play of each step it takes to stdout. So in this case you could do:

```bash
logrotate -d /etc/logrotate.conf
```

The output will tell you what exactly is going on. Also, if you want to narrow down the debug output you can do

```bash
logrotate -d /etc/logrotate.d/messages
```

Though you may want to temporarily place the main logrotate.conf options in that files block since specifying the file directly means it will have never read the main configs options. Specifying the individual file also means you can use the `-f` (force) option in combination with the debug option to get a look at an actual rotation of the messages file taking place.

Comment: I tried running logrotate manually like you suggested, and it tells me it's compressing the logs, but I don't find any compressed logs anywhere. See my question above for details.

Comment: rename the 5 oldest messages files so that they end with a .gz and see if logrotate removes the oldest one like it should. If it does then we know the globbing is failing due to gzip not running correctly. This will at least confirm that the lack of compression is to blame for the lack of rotation.

Comment: Done, details added to the question above. I'm curious whether there's some contention issue with the live `/var/log/messages` file and the `delaycompress` option will help.

Comment: Another interesting point that I found out. When you enable -d option, logrotate command wouldn't touch the log files. Check the manual for more info. `-d, --debug` `Turns on debug mode and implies -v. In debug mode, no changes will be made to the logs or to the logrotate state file.`

Answer (score 1):

Consider trying this setting in your logrotate.conf:

```
dateformat .%Y%m%d
```

and rename your existing messages files to use a dot instead of a dash. Then try your logrotate again.

The clues below led me to believe that the dash may be causing the glob to fail if it's being interpreted somehow as an option (where -- would fix this). It doesn't make sense, but it just might be possible.

```
dateext suffix '-20100224'
glob pattern '-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
glob finding old rotated logs failed
```

Comment: I don't think this is the root cause. The current date format, with a dash, works just fine for other log files. The difference between those log files and `/var/log/messages` is that the rotated `/var/log/messages` files are not compressed.